# Rails - How to validate a field only if a another field has a certain value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3, model

In my form I have a Select with three values: **Apple**, **Banana** and **Cherry**. If I choose **Apple** from the select I hide another Select- and a Text-field with some Javascript, because when **Apple** is chosen, there is no need to fill in these other two fields anymore.

So now I have a problem with validating my form when it's submitted.
I've found some similar problems for example in the case of
"Only validate a field if another is blank."

This problem was solved like this:

```
validates_presence_of :mobile_number, :unless => :home_phone?
```

So I've just tried the first thing which popped into my mind:

```
validates_presence_of :state, :granted_at, :if => :type != 1
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
undefined method `validate' for true:TrueClass
```

How can I conditionally perform a validation on a field based on whether or not another field has a particular value?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because it is executable code you need to wrap it in a lambda or a Proc object like so:

```
validates_presence_of :state, :granted_at, :if => lambda { |o| o.type != 1 }

# alternatively:
..., :if => lambda { self.type != 1 }
..., :if => Proc.new { |o| o.type != 1 }
..., :if ->(o) { o.type != 1 }
```

Comment: thank you for the fast response :) but what contains this block variable "o"? the object which is being validated?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Also take a look at @Hauleth's answer where you can find other ways of solving your problem. The definitive reference can be found in the Rails API Documentation: http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html hope that helps. Furthermore I suggest you google for "ruby procs and blocks" to learn about the basic (ruby) building blocks behind this. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 27):

You can use `if` flag and lambda:

```
validates_presence_of :state, :granted_at, :if => lambda {self.type != 1}
```

Or just create private method:

```
validates_presence_of :state, :granted_at, :if => :valid_type?

private
def valid_type?
  type != 1
end
```

Comment: Please can you explain a scenario where using private function is necessary or better instead of lambda/Proc or vice-versa...Just for understanding purpose.Thanks.

Comment: Method can be public, this doesn’t require private method.

Comment: No .. What i meant was can you give example where in 1 case lambda/proc is better and in 1 case a function makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: @HuzaifaSaifuddin Functionally it makes no difference if you use a lambda or a private method. In almost every situation however I would prefer the private method for readability. Not only because the pure syntax is more readable, but because it forces you to think of a proper name for the expression.

Answer (score 2):

although the above mentioned ways are best practices but you can also make it simple like this:

```
validates_presence_of :state, :granted_at, :if => "type!=1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on the previous answers, you can also use a shorter "arrow" syntax

```
validates :state, :granted_at, presence: true, if: ->(o) { o.type != 1 }
```