# validate a form field depending on radio button value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I not using ActiveRecords rather using ActiveModel to validate form data.
I am stuck into some point where i needed to validate a form field depending on a radio button value.

My model is

```
 class Payment
    include ActiveModel::Model
    attr_accessor :method_id, :crad_name
    validates_presence_of :card_name, :if => :method_type? 

   private
   def method_type?
     self.method_id == 1
   end
 end
```

Here, method_id = 1 for credit card and method_id = 2 for bank

That does not validate the form field and does not show any error either.

I have searched in google and got some valuable stuff for here [Rails - How to validate a field only if a another field has a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848601/rails-how-to-validate-a-field-only-if-a-another-field-has-a-certain-value?answertab=active#tab-top)

But it does not work in this case. Thanks in advance for your suggestion and help

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  I'd like to say first though that using Method as a model name isn't a great idea, as it's generally considered a reserved word.  Moving on.

```
class Payment
  attr_accessor :method_id, crad_name
  validates_presence_of :card_name, :unless => :method_id.nil? 

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @trh but problem is i have two options for radio button method_id = 1 for credit card and method_id = 2 for Bank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Payment
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :method_id, :crad_name
  validates_presence_of :card_name, :if => lambda { |pay| pay.method_id == 1 }
end
```

**EDIT** 
Try this or refer [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

```
class Payment
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :method_id, :crad_name
  validates :card_name, presence: true, if: :method_type?

  private

  def method_type?
    method_id == 1
  end      
end
```

This should work for sure or god help me!